# How to remove the border-bottom from heading tags in GitHub readme?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

I am searching for a way to remove the line appearing below the h1 and h2 tags (# and ## in markdown). Is there something I can do to remove it

[Image of border-bottom in GitHub readme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X05CS.png)

Comment: I searched for it, but couldn't get a specific answer. Somewhere on the StackOverflow, it was stated that GitHub doesn't allow it for security reasons